# WebDriver + swtichTo another browser

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have seen umpteen posts talking about working with pop window using window handle. 
But how to work with a browser which is opened when clicked on a button -

```
<button class="power_buy_now_button" type="button"> 
</button>
```

I tried to get window handle but each time I encounter a changing string, some thing like - "8c5f028e-e7cc-4d0f-afe4-983bb119391e"

There is not even title associated with new browser. More over I am not sure how I would use title to bring control to new browser. And then at some point I would have to bring control back to first browser.

Comment: Is there any taker for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to do something like the following:

```
// This code assumes you start with only one browser window in your test.
// If you have more than one browser window, your code will be more complex.
string originalHandle = driver.GetWindowHandle();
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("power_buy_now_button")).Click();

// May need to wait for window handles collection to have a .Count of 2,
// as clicks are asynchronous.
string popupHandle = string.Empty;
ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.GetWindowHandles();
foreach (string handle in windowHandles)
{
    if (handle != originalHandle)
    {
        popupHandle = handle;
        break;
    }
}

driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupHandle);
// Do stuff in the popup window, eventually closing it with driver.Close()
driver.SwitchTo().Window(originalHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in picking second handle and click on that. This approach works and I hope I would be able to get control back to main window also.